# Angular 10 get router active fragment when scrolling past the fragment?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-router

I'm trying to highlight in the navigation which active fragment you're scrolling past.

Adding the fragment & navigation to the fragment is simple and works well, example:

```
      class="nav-button unselectable"
      matRipple
      routerLink="/"
      fragment="features"
      [ngClass]="{ 'nav-active': (active_fragment | async) === 'features' }"
```

But the router obviously can't know which element you're scrolling about so I'm trying to listen on the scroll event and check the nearest element using the Y position.

But my landing page isn't a child of my navigation so the viewchild doesn't work, example:

navigation component:

```
  @ViewChild('features', { static: false })
  private _features: ElementRef;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  private _update_active_fragment(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    console.log(this._features.nativeElement);
  }
```

Landing page component:

```
  <app-features #features id="features"></app-features>
```

But features native element is undefined.

My question is:

- How else can I achieve this feature?
- How can I get the element ref of  from the navigation component?
- How can I get the y position of the features element in the navigation component?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, are your navigation and landing page components siblings? Do you have a common container component for both of them - like app.component.ts or so?
 Where do you have your logic which reacts on fragment changes in the url? How would you like to continue after you got the y position?

Comment: You can get the _activated_ component by listening to the `activate` event of the `RouterOutlet` directive: `<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>`. I haven't tried this, but I assume you can get the Y coordinate from there.

Comment: @MarcellKiss app.comp contains <navigation> and <router-outlet> which itself will display <landing-page> which contains the <features> fragment. Due to this i can't really have them both as 'shared'.

@ AndreiGătej router outlet by itself does not listen for scroll events and does not check for fragments you're scrolling over. That's only usfeul up to a point.

Comment: Just to be sure, <landing-page> contains multiple features, so you can scroll over them. And you have also multiple navigation buttons, which can make you jump to each of the features. And this works one way (click the button and jump there) but not the other way (activate the button on scrolling). Is that correct?

Comment: @MarcellKiss correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a new navigation service:

```
public active_fragment: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

  constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe((frag) => {
      this.active_fragment.next(frag);
    });
  }
```

In my navigation component:

```
      [ngClass]="{
        'nav-active': (navigationService.active_fragment | async) === 'home'
      }"
```

in my landing component that contains my fragments:

```
  @ViewChild('features', { read: ElementRef })
  private _features: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('benefits', { read: ElementRef })
  private _benefits: ElementRef;


  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  private _update_active_fragment(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    switch (true) {
      case window.pageYOffset >=
        this._some_previous_element.nativeElement.offsetTop &&
        window.pageYOffset <= this._features.nativeElement.offsetTop: {
        this.navigationService.active_fragment.next('network-rail-feedback');
        break;
      }

      case window.pageYOffset >= this._features.nativeElement.offsetTop &&
        window.pageYOffset <= this._benefits.nativeElement.offsetTop: {
        this.navigationService.active_fragment.next('features');
        break;
      }


      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I stumbled across this question, by trying to optimize this bit of code, I wrote several years ago. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eq4j9p

There is a downside of having to compute the visibility on each scroll. Specially if you have a lot of fragments.
I look forward to seeing other solutions. Otherwise I would accept this as an optimzation to the current code, that I have. Thanks!